# Tensor assertion error when trying to split data into test and validation set?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have metabolite data and I'm trying to build a neural network model. I'm getting *assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors) AssertionError* error and I can't figure out what I should do to get this to work.

The issue happens here

```
#Split data into training and validation 70 / 30
data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(np.array(log_metabol)),
                                                torch.Tensor(labels))
train, val = torch.utils.data.random_split(data, [int(0.7 * len(data)), 
                                                              len(data) - int(0.7 * len(data))])
```

The problem seems to originate from the first row of this block. How do I make this work?

Comment: Could you add the shapes of `log_metabol` and `labels`? The error suggests that not all "rows" in you data is the same shape. Also, could you add the full error message / stack trace?

Comment: Traceback:
  File "/home/h/Desktop/neuralnet/neuralnet_train.py", line 36, in <module>
    data = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(torch.Tensor(np.array(log_metabol)),
  File "C:\Users\hamalkre\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataset.py", line 158, in __init__
    assert all(tensors[0].size(0) == tensor.size(0) for tensor in tensors)
AssertionError

and shape log_metabol:
(9, 9152)